# In iOS 7, why view height different from the same view in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have an view controller which is the root view controller of a `UINavigationController`, and the `UINavigationController` is the controller of a `UITabBarViewController`

like this structure:

```
UITabBarViewController->UINavigationViewController->UIViewController
```

But the problem is, when I use self.view.frame.size.height property of this view controller, I get different result.

In iOS 6, I get 548. But in iOS 7, I get 568. So I can place my custom subview accurately because its position based the height of the view.

Comment: Please read the iOS 7 UI Transition Guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1) which covers the changes to the status bar and how to deal with them.

Comment: why nobody ever reads the official documentation...?

Comment: You really shouldn't be setting frames manually anyway.  AutoLayout has been recommended for a good few releases now.  It has its problems, but for generic views it's pretty good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS7 views go under the navigation bar, you can stop your views going under the navigation bar in your viewController:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```